# Updating Reactive Value Breaks invalidateLater

Tags: r, shiny

In following shiny application:

When click the button, it prints to console once per second.

```r
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("text"),
  actionButton("button","Click to Start")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    myVal <- reactiveVal(0)
    startCount <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
    observeEvent(input$button,{
        startCount(TRUE)
    })

    observe({
        req(startCount())
        req(myVal() < 5)
        invalidateLater(1000)
        newVal <-myVal() + 1
        # myVal(newVal)
        print(myVal())
    })

    output$text <- renderText(myVal())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By removing comment `# myVal(newVal)`, it prints 1 to 5 in the console, and displays 5 in the UI. But there are two issues:

1. `invalidateLater` stops working, it doesn't wait for one second any more.
2. The UI jumps to 5 instantly, instead of showing 1,2,3,4,5 with one second interval.

What should I do to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `isolate` to avoid recursively triggering the observer:

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("text"),
  actionButton("button","Click to Start")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myVal <- reactiveVal(0)
  startCount <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    startCount(TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    req(startCount())
    req(isolate(myVal()) < 5)
    invalidateLater(1000)
    isolate(myVal(myVal() + 1))
    print(myVal())
  })

  output$text <- renderText(myVal())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```